# How extract string from another string

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose to have this string:

```
http://192.168.56.101:4567/compose?p=/topic/3/werwerwerwer
```

I need to extract this:

```
/topic/3/werwerwerwer
```

At the end I must obtain 3! Anyone can help me?

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Will the structure of the string always be the same? i.e. Same slashes and all. If so you could do an ugly string search targeting the `/` but it may not be very reusable or modular. Look into `yourStr.split('/')` as well as `parseInt()`, these may be of usable value.

Answer (score 1):

This should put your in the right way. After calling getParam, all you need to do is apply the regular expression.

```js
/**
 * Get the value of a querystring
 * @param  {String} param The field to get the value of
 */
var getParam = function ( field, url ) {
    // this regex will match the first parameter with the given name and return
    // into the group #1 the value 
    var reg = new RegExp( '[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)');
    var string = reg.exec(url);
    return string ? string[1] : null;
};

var p = getParam("p", "http://192.168.56.101:4567/compose?p=/topic/3/werwerwerwer")
if (p != null) {
   var myRegexp = /^\/\w+\/(\d+)\/.*/; // The group #1 will extract the number
   var match = myRegexp.exec(p);
   alert(match[1]); // 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your string is an URL and p is the parameter value you try to retrieve you can get it like this:

```
var string = 'http://192.168.56.101:4567/compose?p=/topic/3/werwerwerwer'
function get(name, link){
   if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '=([^&]*)')).exec(link))
      return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}

var theValueOfp = get('p',string);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yb4se4cz/1/